# in selenium script not able to get dom ids for focupanel and verticalpanel

Tags: gwt, webdriver

my problem is setting dom ids for below panels.Am not able to get the ids in selenium script
     am giving id for FocusPanel and VerticalPanel like

```
    focusPanel.ensureDebugId("focusPanel");
    and also
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>  in gwt.xml file
    but it is not taking ids for these panels am not able get these panels in selenium script        


    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"focusPanel"}
    Command duration or timeout: 15.02 seconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-18 09:51:02'
    System info: host: 'INHYDRMOTURI2', ip: '10.91.115.72', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
    Session ID: 76ec6eca-405c-47be-a5ba-7ea11d3ca515
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=27.0.1}]

    can u suggest me how to set dom ids for verticalpanel and focuspanel
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it for setting ids

```
focusPanel.getElement().setId("focusPanel");
```

In case of `ensureDebugId()` the Id will become `gwt-debug-[your id]`.

for e.g.

```
focusPanel.ensureDebugId("focusPanel");
```

the id for `focusPanel` will be `gwt-debug-focusPanel`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. i tried by set id gwt-debug-focusPanel but it is not identifying the panel giving same exception

Comment: What have you tried. Share that line please where you are setting ID. You have to call `focusPanel.getElement().setId("focusPanel");`. remove `ensureDebugId()` call.

Comment: first i tried with focusPanel.ensureDebugId("focusPanel"); then i tried with focusPanel.getElement().setId("focusPanel"); and in selenium script driver.findElement(By.id("focusPanel")).click(); it is giving org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"focusPanel"}    exception.

Comment: And also am using webdriverwait before click event of focus panel wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("focusPanel")));

Comment: Do you have firebug plugin in Firefox. Try to get element by `document.getElementById("focusPanel")` first if its working then there is some issue with `By.id("focusPanel")`. I don't have any idea about selenium but you can try `By.id("gwt-debug-focusPanel")` also.

Comment: i have firebug plugin in my firefox. can u tell me what this document object related to